# Testing concurrent/parallel execution

Tags: testing, scala, concurrency, akka

I'm currently writing a small framework for demand-driven workflows. The API is now stable and I am working on improving tests. It's easy to show that computations are correct (which is a good start), however, the main interest of the framework is to launch subtasks  in parallel (when needed and possible).

Is there a way to test automatically that two different pieces of code do run in a parallel/concurrent fashion ? I prefer not relying on execution time (speed-up) measurments.

The framework is written in scala, and relies a lot on Akka Futures.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example:

```
val foo = step {
  //... defines an arbitrary task
}

// Runs 5 times the code inside step foo
val foos = repeat( 5 )( foo )
```

I would like to be sure that the code inside `foo` is executed 5 times in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this without changing tasks (i.e. when you need to test that two **specific** tasks run in parallel). But if you can change the tasks, just add an actor to the system. Make every task send messages to this actor when starting or ending work. If the actor receives two `Starting` messages in a row, the tasks should be running in parallel (or at least in different threads).

Comment: I like the idea, but are you sure of the absolute ordering of messages in actor mailbox ?

Comment: @paradigmatic: http://akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html doesn't seem to say anything about ordering, unfortunately, including guarantees which I expect any actor implementation to provide.

Comment: you can just use timestamps in the messages, then line up messages on timestamps at the end of the test and build an "events timeline"..

Answer (score 1):

This test does not make any sense to me. On a computer with less than 5 cores you cannot get a parallelism of 5. It seems like you are testing Akka, which we are already doing, so just relax and test the dispatcher settings to verify that when it will run it will have the desired effect.

Hope that helps,

Cheers,
√

Comment: I am not trying to test if akka dispatchers work, but rather if I was able to start the task and combine the futures correctly. I introduced some bugs which made some code sequential and I want to be sure this will never happen again. (BTW: machines with more than 4 cores are not uncommon these days)

Comment: Then perhaps the question is mis-stated, how did you make the code sequential?

Comment: By combining futures with `flatMap` without having triggered the execution earlier (ie. futures where created inside for comprehension). I want to avoid this kind of mistake.

Comment: Ah, alright, this is easy to overlook when it comes to for-comprehensions since the flatMap is "hidden".